# How to use bean validation in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, bean-validation

Is there any way to use bean validation in Tomcat without use TomEE?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks

(Updated)

I have included the following to my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>4.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

However, the following JSF page doesn't show the validation error message in Tomcat.

```
<h:form id="validateID">
    <h:outputLabel for="id" value="ID : " title="id" />
        <h:inputText id="myid" value="#{validationDemoManagedBean.myid}"
        title="id" tabindex="8" size="20">
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message  for="myid" style="color:red" />
        <h:commandButton value="Validate" type="submit" />
</h:form>
```

Our validationDemoManagedBean backing bean has the following

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ValidationDemoManagedBean implements Serializable {

@Pattern(regexp = "\\d{7}\\(\\d{1}\\)", message = "Must in pattern 9999999(9)")
private String myid = "";

. . . 
}
```

We don't have specified any default validator in faces-config.xml.

Validation error message should able to be shown when this application is run in TomEE and user enter any invalid ID text and click on Validate button. However, this won't work in tomcat. Is there anything that I have missed in my deployment to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Bean Validation doesn't depend on JavaEE, you can just add the JARs of a provider such as Hibernate Validator to your application class path or the "lib" directory of your server. For Hibernate Validator, you can learn more about the required dependencies [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createproject). Also refer to this [FAQ entry](http://hibernate.org/validator/faq/#does-hibernate-validator-5-x-work-with-tomcat-6) to learn more about using Hibernate Validator 5 on Tomcat 6.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar, 
My issue is that I have already included the hibernate-validator in the pom.xml However, JSF still not able to validate the backing bean after user click on submit button. (Remark: I don't have any default validator in my face.config.xml) The same application work in tomEE.  I will update my Question to reflect the situation.

Comment: You will only get an integration of JSF and BV out of the box in a Java EE container (the JSF spec says in 2.5.7: "A JSF implentation must support JSR 303 Bean Validation if the environment in which the JSF runtime is included requires JSR 303 Bean Validation. Currently the only such environment is when JSF is included in a Java EE [...] runtime"). So in a non-SE environment (such as pure Tomcat) you'd have to set-up the required integration points yourself. You could have a look at the TomEE code base to learn how they did it, but then again I'd say you could use TomEE itself to begin with.